Duplicate the Item Ranking - Top 50 with description' report via the Data Feeds API
I'm attempting to duplicate the 'Item Ranking - Top 50 with description' report via the Data Feeds API.
I require this data to be stored in our reporting database.
Currently, I am utilizing the following endpoints:

UPC Sales
UPC Attribution
Calendar
Store
UPC Custom Attribution

Do I need to use additional endpoints  to obtain the report, or if another API should be used? any tip?
I've used the above end points but data is not matching with the report that was generated in Walmart.
The model colummn is missing as well.
